# Compare data from two columns from data table against variables in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, datatable

**So I am practicing using a databases with ASP.Net...**

I have two datatable columns from Northwind database. One is `Product.ProductID` and the other is `Product.UnitsInStock`. I need to compare that with a collection (SortedList) of objects. Essentially comparing variables Product ID and quantity(client side). The objects are a `ICollection` Value saved in a `Session["cart"]`.

How can I compare the variables I have of product id and units in stock against the DataTable columns 1 is Products.ProductID and second column is Products.UnitsInStock?

Here is the query and roughly how I thought I could grab these variables from the database.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

if (dt.Columns.Count != 0 &&
       dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        int quantityOfUnit = 0;
        int productID = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < dt.Columns.Count; index++)
        {
            if (index == indexOfUnitsInStock)//indexOfUnitsInStock = 1
            {
                quantityOfUnit = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][index].ToString());
            }
            else//index = 0
            {
                productID = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][index].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Building a new query:

```
foreach (object items in ((ShoppingCart)Session["cart"]).Values)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection((string)Application["DBConnectionString"]);
    string selectionString =
        "SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.UnitsInStock " +
            "FROM Products" +
            "WHERE Products.ProductID = " +
            ((ShoppingCart)Session["cart"]).Values;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand cm = new OleDbCommand(selectionString, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cm;   
        da.Fill(dt);
        da.Dispose();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        txtUnderstockedItems.Text = "There was a problem connecting to the database: " + ex.Message ;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you generally do not want to concatenate SQL in the way you are doing. Use [parameterized SQL](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries). If these are Integer values, you can cast them to integers and then put them in the query and achieve a similar result.

If ShoppingCart.Values is a collection, then you have a few choices.

1. Issue the query one at a time, for each item in Values
2. Build a query that uses a sql list "WHERE Products.ProductID IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4)" - the list you would build by iterating values
3. Create a stored procedure that performs the query and use an XML [parameter](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx) to supply the list values.

Out of the 3, the third would be my preference as its safer and probably easier to maintain over the long run.

An example of #1 would be something like this...

```
foreach (object obj in (ShoppingCart)Session["cart"].Values)
{
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  int productID = (int)obj;
  string query = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ?";   //yuck, oledb params
  using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection (connStr))
  {
     //dont hold me to this syntax, its from my head
     OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
     cmd.Parameters.Add(productID);
     OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();
     da.SelectCommand = cm;   
     da.Fill(dt);
  }
  //do something with the data table
}
```

Comment: mind showing me what you mean by issue the query one at a time??

Comment: Example provided for OLEDB, note the using wrapping the connection will take care of the Finally code that would normally be required for object disposals.